# Symfony2 Database Config

Tags: php, sql, database, symfony

I've just inherited a Symfony2 project from a former co-worker. I'm trying to get it running locally, but am getting a SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused error. I guess I'm missing the database connection that I've read should be in the app/config/parameters.yml file.

Is there anyway of finding this information if all I have is the project and the live site?

Comment: You must indeed configure the database parameters in `app/config/parameters.yml`. Then if the database is not created, you can create it with `php app/console doctrine:database:create`.

Comment: It depends on your Symfony DB Bundle. For example if you use Doctrine, take a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html If you use MongoDB take a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/config.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's standard Symfony2 project you have to configure your database connection information in `app/config/parameters.yml`, like:

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    database_driver:    pdo_mysql
    database_host:      localhost
    database_name:      test_project
    database_user:      root
    database_password:  password

# ...
```

More in [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#configuring-the-database).

After that you have to create database:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:database:create
```

Next, create table schema:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Also, you could load (if your co-worker provided it ; ) some data fixtures, so try:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load
```

If your coworker doesn't use doctrine fixtures you should consider dumping data from your prod database.